# Does monotouch support WinForms and DataGridView Virtual Mode?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I currently have a WinForms application that downloads large amounts of data from a WCF service. To display the data quickly, I use DataGridView Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading. Being new to IPAD development, monotouch seems like a good option for a C# developer. But I have a concern that involves displaying large amounts of data in a grid. **Does monotouch support DataGridView and Virtual Mode? If not,then how can monotouch display lots of data quickly?** 
**Or should I use objective C?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

monotouch doesn't have winforms, it wraps (has bindings to) the CocoaTouch API.

I've never used monotouch (or anything mono, unfortunately), but it would appear that UITableView might be what you want?

http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView

More info about the API's available from MonoTouch:

http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/API